# after install blender-2.83.5-windows64.msi and clicking to launch app a window pops open for a split second then closes and the app fails to pen

Tags: error, installation

trying blender for the first time after install and clicking to launch app a window pops open for a split second then closes and the app fails to open

installed blender-2.83.5-windows64.msi

also tried blender-2.90.0-21cb6f09ffa8-windows64 zip folder

updated system and graphics cards
thinkstation p330
nvidia quadro p2200 opengl

display adapter also updated for intel(r) UHD Graphics 630

### this is the basic error

PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83> ./blender.exe
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x0000000000000000
PS C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83>

---

This is the blender crash save from the 2.90.0

## Blender 2.90.0, Commit date: 2020-08-25 16:00, Hash 21cb6f09ffa8

```
# backtrace
Exception Record:

ExceptionCode         : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Exception Address     : 0x0000000000000000
Exception Module      : 
Exception Flags       : 0x00000000
Exception Parameters  : 0x2
    Parameters[0] : 0x0000000000000008
    Parameters[1] : 0x0000000000000000


Stack trace:
blender.exe         :0x00007FF6369677B0  bli_windows_system_backtrace_stack_thread
blender.exe         :0x00007FF636966A20  BLI_system_backtrace
blender.exe         :0x00007FF632B65D40  windows_exception_handler
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD282F400  UnhandledExceptionFilter
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD5702F80  memset
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56EC5C0  _C_specific_handler
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD57010B0  _chkstk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56C9E70  RtlRaiseException
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FFE10  KiUserExceptionDispatcher


Threads:
Thread : 00000b04
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF9F0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56938D0  RtlInitializeResource
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00002764
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF9F0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56938D0  RtlInitializeResource
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000027ec
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF9F0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56938D0  RtlInitializeResource
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000021a0
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001c20
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000cc4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000df8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000016c8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00001458
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 0000168c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00003050
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653D600  IlmThread_2_4::Semaphore::wait
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653CDD0  IlmThread_2_4::ThreadPool::numThreads
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63653DA80  std::_LaunchPad<std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<void (__cdecl IlmThread_2_4::Thread::*)(void) __ptr64,Il
blender.exe         :0x00007FF63576CBC0  std::_Pad::_Call_func
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000026f4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF990  NtWaitForAlertByThreadId
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56C0460  RtlSleepConditionVariableSRW
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD2755850  SleepConditionVariableSRW
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFF9FE2BA70  _crtSetThreadpoolWait
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFF9FE02650  std::_Winerror_message
MSVCP140.dll        :0x00007FFF9FE02650  std::_Winerror_message
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BB5670  alcGetInteger64vSOFT
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000b50
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BB5670  alcGetInteger64vSOFT
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BB5670  alcGetInteger64vSOFT
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000031c4
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FC0E0  NtWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD27689F0  WaitForSingleObjectEx
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
OpenAL32.dll        :0x00007FFF78BA0080  alGetError
ucrtbase.dll        :0x00007FFFD3490D40  beginthreadex
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 000033d8
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FCBB0  NtWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE.dll      :0x00007FFFD2787EB0  WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
combase.dll         :0x00007FFFD3C36310  CStdStubBuffer_Disconnect
combase.dll         :0x00007FFFD3C36310  CStdStubBuffer_Disconnect
combase.dll         :0x00007FFFD3C36310  CStdStubBuffer_Disconnect
combase.dll         :0x00007FFFD3C36310  CStdStubBuffer_Disconnect
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 00000068
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF9F0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56938D0  RtlInitializeResource
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Thread : 0000217c
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56FF9F0  NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56938D0  RtlInitializeResource
KERNEL32.DLL        :0x00007FFFD3EE7BC0  BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll.dll           :0x00007FFFD56CCE30  RtlUserThreadStart


Loaded Modules :
0x00007FF632A60000 2.9.0.0              blender.exe C:\Users\svihtelic.BBBNT\Downloads\blender-2.90.0-21cb6f09ffa8-windows64\blender-2.90.0-21cb6f09ffa8-windows64\blender.pdb 
0x00007FFFD5660000 10.0.18362.815       ntdll.dll  
0x00007FFFD3ED0000 10.0.18362.959       KERNEL32.DLL  
0x00007FFFD2730000 10.0.18362.997       KERNELBASE.dll  
0x00007FFFD39E0000 10.0.18362.997       USER32.dll  
0x00007FFFD26E0000 10.0.18362.1016      win32u.dll  
0x00007FFFD37C0000 10.0.18362.1         GDI32.dll  
0x00007FFFD3570000 10.0.18362.1016      gdi32full.dll  
0x00007FFFD2640000 10.0.18362.815       msvcp_win.dll  
0x00007FFFD3470000 10.0.18362.815       ucrtbase.dll  
0x00007FFFD46F0000 10.0.18362.997       SHELL32.dll  
0x00007FFFD3220000 10.0.18362.387       cfgmgr32.dll  
0x00007FFFD4020000 10.0.18362.959       shcore.dll  
0x00007FFFD4650000 7.0.18362.1          msvcrt.dll  
0x00007FFFB0100000 10.0.18362.1         SHFOLDER.dll  
0x00007FFFD37F0000 10.0.18362.628       RPCRT4.dll  
0x00007FFFD3B80000 10.0.18362.997       combase.dll  
0x00007FFFD3270000 10.0.18362.836       bcryptPrimitives.dll  
0x00007FFFD2A90000 10.0.18362.997       windows.storage.dll  
0x00007FFFD5110000 10.0.18362.959       sechost.dll  
0x00007FFFD3710000 10.0.18362.752       advapi32.dll  
0x00007FFFD2590000 10.0.18362.693       profapi.dll  
0x00007FFFD2540000 10.0.18362.1         powrprof.dll  
0x00007FFFD2510000                      UMPDC.dll  
0x00007FFFD4400000 10.0.18362.1         shlwapi.dll  
0x00007FFFD2520000 10.0.18362.1         kernel.appcore.dll  
0x00007FFFD2710000 10.0.18362.1         cryptsp.dll  
0x00007FFFD4390000 10.0.18362.387       WS2_32.dll  
0x00007FFFA2F00000 10.0.18362.387       OPENGL32.dll  
0x00007FFFD4230000 10.0.18362.693       ole32.dll  
0x00007FFFD3EC0000 10.0.18362.1         PSAPI.DLL  
0x00007FFFD4620000 10.0.18362.387       IMM32.dll  
0x00007FFFAD380000 2019.9.0.0           tbb.dll  
0x00007FFF76A50000 58.29.100.0          avformat-58.dll  
0x00007FFF5EE10000 58.54.100.0          avcodec-58.dll  
0x00007FFF61A30000 3.7.7150.1013        python37.dll  
0x00007FFFAC980000 58.8.100.0           avdevice-58.dll  
0x00007FFFD3910000 10.0.18362.959       OLEAUT32.dll  
0x00007FFFA1470000 5.5.100.0            swscale-5.dll  
0x00007FFF9FE90000 56.31.100.0          avutil-56.dll  
0x00007FFFD3440000 10.0.18362.267       bcrypt.dll  
0x0000000070440000 1.0.28.0             libsndfile-1.dll  
0x00007FFF9FDF0000 14.26.28720.3        MSVCP140.dll  
0x00007FFFAD600000 14.26.28720.3        VCRUNTIME140.dll  
0x00007FFFB50E0000 2019.9.0.0           tbbmalloc_proxy.dll  
0x00007FFFB50C0000 14.26.28720.3        VCRUNTIME140_1.dll  
0x00007FFFAB680000 10.0.18362.1         AVIFIL32.dll  
0x00007FFFC23D0000 6.10.18362.1016      COMCTL32.dll  
0x00007FFFCBD70000 10.0.18362.1         VERSION.dll  
0x00007FFFA2E90000 10.0.18362.387       GLU32.dll  
0x00007FFFD0EF0000 10.0.18362.1         dbghelp.dll  
0x00007FFFCBB80000 10.0.18362.1         Secur32.dll  
0x00007FFF78B90000 1.20.1.0             OpenAL32.dll  
0x00007FFFAB660000 10.0.18362.1         AVICAP32.dll  
0x00007FFF79770000 2.0.12.0             SDL2.dll  
0x00007FFFD51B0000 10.0.18362.1         SETUPAPI.dll  
0x00007FFFAB630000 10.0.18362.1         MSVFW32.dll  
0x00007FFFCC420000 10.0.18362.1         MSACM32.dll  
0x00007FFFD0320000 10.0.18362.1         WINMM.dll  
0x00007FFFD02F0000 10.0.18362.1         winmmbase.dll  
0x00007FFFD1210000 10.0.18362.1         dxcore.dll  
0x00007FFFD2430000 10.0.18362.1         SSPICLI.DLL  
0x0000000070680000                      libfftw3-3.dll  
0x00007FFFA1440000 3.5.100.0            swresample-3.dll  
0x00007FFFA0DA0000 2019.9.0.0           tbbmalloc.dll  
0x00007FFFD0530000 10.0.18362.449       uxtheme.dll  
0x00007FFFD4EB0000 2001.12.10941.16384  clbcatq.dll  
0x00007FFFCA5D0000 10.0.18362.387       MMDevApi.dll  
0x00007FFFD2310000 10.0.18362.387       DEVOBJ.dll  
0x00007FFFCA650000 10.0.18362.815       AUDIOSES.DLL  
0x00007FFFCDE00000 10.0.18362.997       wintypes.dll  
0x00007FFFD0860000 10.0.18362.959       resourcepolicyclient.dll  
0x00007FFFD44E0000 10.0.18362.900       MSCTF.dll  
0x00007FFFA59D0000 10.0.18362.836       dataexchange.dll  
0x00007FFFCF700000 10.0.18362.387       d3d11.dll  
0x00007FFFCF960000 10.0.18362.959       dcomp.dll  
0x00007FFFD1390000 10.0.18362.815       dxgi.dll  
0x00007FFFD05F0000 10.0.18362.959       twinapi.appcore.dll  
0x00007FFFD0A40000 10.0.18362.267       RMCLIENT.dll  
0x00007FFF5DEA0000 27.20.100.8587       ig9icd64.dll  
0x00007FFFD0B30000 10.0.18362.267       dwmapi.dll  
 
# Python backtrace
```

I spent some time doing google research on the issue and i'm not finding anything to try.

Comment: First make sure that your graphics driver for both the UHD 630 and Quadro card are up-to-date. If this doesn't help, try the workaround suggested [here](https://developer.blender.org/T78799). If the workaround fixes the issue, please leave a comment on [this ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T72098) with your affected GPU combination.

Comment: Thanks for the link..that work around did in fact allow it the launch and open.